# How to set the choices of a Symfony EntityType form field after the form has been created and handled?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am working with `Symfony 3.4` and would like to create a simple form which presents a list entities which can be selected for deletion using checkboxes:

- The controller which creates and handles the form loads a list of entities from the DB which are then added to the form.
- The controller uses some additional parameters to offer paging, e.g. if there are 10.000 entities in the DB the user can choose to load only the first 50.

The problem is, that "the first 50 entities" depends on wether entities have been delete / the form has been handled.

- To handle the form in the controller I have to create it first
- To create the form I need to load a list of entities from the DB to set them as `choises`
- This list will contain the first 50 entities
- If the user has chosen to delete the first 10 entities this is done when handling the form.

---

```
class SomeController
{
    public function deleteUsersAction(Request $request)
    {
        $users = $this->loadUsersFromDB(50);

        $form = $this->creatFormBuilder()
            ->add('users', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
                'choices' => $users,                  // $users are added here
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ])
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $users = $form->getData();
            $this->deleteUsers($user);

            // Load the now first 50 users
            $users = $this->loadUsersFromDB(50);

            // How to add these users to the form??
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle::user_list.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
    }
}
```

**How to set the correct users to the form after the submitted users have been deleted?**

---

### Edit

To answer a question from the comments I provide a small example:

- Let's say the form shows the first 5 users.
- When the page is called the first time the form is not submitted. The controller loads the following first users, uses them to create the form and to display the page:
- Bob
- Alice
- Mike
- John
- Bill
- On the page the user selects **Bob** and **Alice** for deletion and submits the form.
- The controller is called again, and the list of the first 5 users is loaded to create the form. This list is exactly the same as before.
- However, as the form was now submitted the data is handled and Bob and Alice are deleted.
- Now we cannot return the created form because it still contains the entries for Bob and Alice...
- We have to run `$users = $this->loadUsersFromDB(5)` again to get the correct result, like
- Mike
- John
- Bill
- Jim
- Tom

**The Problem:**

- The list of users has to be loaded **before** the form is created, because we need this list to create the form.
- The form has to be created so that we can handle it
- Handling the form does change the list of users
- Thus after handling the form we need to load the list of users again.

**So:** Loading the list of users before to form is handled is necessary work, because the list changes when the form is handled.

**How can this work be avoided?**

Of course loading 5 users as in the example is no big deal, but in real code this might be hundreds of *heavy* entities and running the same code twice might have a significant performance impact.

Comment: The easiest solution is to recreate the Form.

Comment: What “set correct users after the form submission” means? If you mean to load next 50 users it’s really easy, just return $this->redirectToRoute(YOUR_ROUTE); inside the iIF statement and you will have a clean page with new data.

Comment: @AlexanderDimitrov Loading the list of users **befor** the form is handled is totally unnecessary work because this list changes when the form is handled. I tried to clarify when editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not understood my proposal in the comment, so I'll explain here in more detail /also now I write from the laptop :)/

````
class SomeController {
    public function deleteUsersAction(Request request) {
        $users = $this->loadUsersFromDB(50);        

        $form = $this->creatFormBuilder()
            ->add('users', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
                'choices' => $users,                  // $users are added here
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ])
            ->getForm();

         $form->handleRequest($request);
         if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
             $users = $form->getData();
             $this->deleteUsers($user);

             // Load the now first 50 users
             $users = $this->loadUsersFromDB(50); <-- you don't need this

             // Q: How to add these users to the form??
             // A: When you return a redirect response to the same page /you can also pass any query parameters if you had any filters and etc../
             //    This will ensure that the page is loaded properly with the new list of the users and Bob and Alice will NOT be in the list
             //    If you don't do it with a redirect and the user submits the form the browser remembers the data and if the users hits the refresh button of the browser it will resubmit the form and with your approach it may delete next 2 users /Mike and John/.
             return $this->redirectToRoute('YOUR_ROUTE', $request->query->all());
         }

         return $this->render('AppBundle::user_list.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
    }
}```
````

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, however this leads to the same problem I tried to describe: **How to avoid to load the user list twice?** Your write that I do not need re-load the user list after the form was handled but should re-direct to the same page instead to get fresh data. This would work of course but re-loading the page is just another way to reload the data. Thus the user list would still be loaded twice while re-loading the page would add additional work load. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you remove the line inside the list statement and make the redirect, then the list will load only once per page request. That means:
User loads the page (1 loading of the list) -> Form is submitted (1 loading of the list) -> Page is redirected (1 loading of the list)

Comment: Exactly! If the form is not submitted (first load of the page) the list is loaded only once. But when the form is submitted the list is loaded twice. A first time when the form is handled and a second time when handling the redirect request. **How to avoid loading the list twice when the form is submitted?**

Comment: You need to go on different route there... with your current setup I don't see a better approach, because you need all these 3 loading from the list anyway.
1st: Load the list as a source
2nd: Process the list
3rd: Load fresh list

Personally I didn't do any batch processing /deleting/ with the symfony forms, because there are many things wich can go wrong like what will happen if there is a new entity between the transactions, what will happen in case of an error etc.

Comment: OK, so we agree that your proposal is not a solution for the question *"How to avoid loading the list twice on form submission"*. In short your answer is "You cannot / should not avoid loading the list twice because loading the list twice is bad for performance but still is the cleanest approach". Right? :-)

Comment: Not really :) You can avoid the approach with the form then you will load the list then  when the user selects entities from the list for deletion and click the button it can make an AJAX call only with the selected IDs. The backend when it handles the deletion it will not load the list of the users, but it will handle the deletion by the provided IDs. On success the front-end will reload the page and now you will have new loading of the list with the fresh data. This approach needs only two loads of the list and also the deletion will consume less memory...